# Can I communicate with virtual serial device using jssc? Problem with ttyS0 configuration (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, serial-port, tty, jssc

I am working with jssc library. I want to emulate ELM327 device and I have already found OBDSim (https://icculus.org/obdgpslogger/obdsim.html).

I am in dialout group.

While mounting OBDSim on tty0, simple code:

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;
import jssc.SerialPortList;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();
     for(int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
     System.out.println(portNames[i]);
     }
}
```

gives me empty list. While connecting real device to USB, this code gives me:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

I read that jssc is searching over ttyUSB* and ttyS* ports, but I am unable to run OBDSim on ttyS0.

```
sudo obdsim -g gui_fltk -t /dev/ttyS0
```

result:

```
tcgetattr tty_device: Input/output error
Error creating virtual port
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone dealing with that kind of issue, here is my tip:

You might want to use socat to create virtual serial port (PTY/PTS) and then mount OBDsim (or other tool) there. Then, symlink this port to ttyUSB*. Jssc will find that. I have no better solution so far and perhaps there won't be any.

Comment: If you are using Linux, then you can also use tty2com null modem driver from SerialPundit project.